# Split repeated string by regex java

Tags: java, regex

From That

```
    String s = "Paper size: A4Paper size: A3Paper size: A2";
```

I need to get A4, A3 and A2. How can I do that?

```
    String regex = "Paper size: (.*?)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){        
        System.out.println( m.group(1));
    }
```

this return empty strings.

edit: at the place of the A3,A4,A5 may be any char sequence, which then next "Paper size" indicates to continue the next group

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dfoa - `([A-Z]\d)`

Comment: Depends on what you can have besides `An`.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("^Paper size: ", "").split("Paper size: ")`.

Answer (score 2):

try this regex:

```
: (.*?)(?:Paper size|$) //global
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF3eR4/1) output:

[image]

Comment: String s = "Loan Postpone - 7 day, pay: 24Loan Postpone - 7f7 day, pay: 25Loan Postpone - 7-9 day, pay: 24.1"; How can I extract from here (7,24) (7f7, 25) and (7-9,24.1) pairs?

Comment: Giorgi, maybe something like `-\s(.*?)\sday,\spay:\s(.*?)(?:L|$)` https://regex101.com/r/gF9pJ2/1

Answer (score 0):

If your values can have any values, you may use a workaround splitting:

```
String s = "Paper size: A4Paper size: A3Paper size: A2";
String[] res = s.replaceFirst("^Paper size:\\s*", "") // Remove the first delimiter to get rid of the empty value
                .split("Paper size:\\s*");            // Split
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); // => [A4, A3, A2]
```

See an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Ttfehk)

Or, you can match any text other than `Paper size:` and capture it with `([^P]*(?:P(?!aper size:)[^P]*)*)`:

```
String s = "Paper size: A4Paper size: A3Paper size: A2";
String pattern1 = "Paper size: ([^P]*(?:P(?!aper size:)[^P]*)*)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find())
    res.add(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(res); // => [A4, A3, A2]
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pTy1bB)

The `Paper size: ([^P]*(?:P(?!aper size:)[^P]*)*)` is actually the same pattern as `(?s)Paper size: (.*?)(?=Paper size: |\z)`, but an unrolled one, a much more efficient with longer inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String s = "Paper size: A4Paper size: A3Paper size: A2";
  String regex = "([A-Z]\\d)";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

  while(m.find()){
     System.out.println( m.group(1));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace your regex with this one : `"Paper size: (..)?"`

OR

`"Paper size: (\\w\\d)?"`

if you wanted to be strict that the captured group always consists of a letter followed by a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get 
Paper size: A4
Paper size: A3
Paper size: A2
use     `String regex = "Paper size: A[234]";`

```
System.out.println(m.group());
```